# Initiate download from javascript code and bypass download window using c#

Tags: c#

I have this link inside a webpage that triggers a download window. Is it possible to download a file directly from this using c# without the download window?

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('CapDirectories$grdFiles$ctl03$ctl01','')">
  Sample_20160307.XLS</a>
```

Comment: I think for security reasons all browsers notify the user when the page wans to download a file. Otherwise, it would be viruses' paradise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, you could download a file directly in C# using the WebClient.

see:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx

You would just need to make sure you had access to the file on the server.  If you are downloading to the local machine through the browser, then yes, security in the browser warns you every time, so you don't download some crazy malware on your machine.

Comment: I think for the C# WebClient it requires a url of the file. Since the download link for the file contains a javascript link above. It does not work. Please let me know if I am wrong on this one.

Comment: Sorry,  thought you only wanted to download through c# and avoid the browser.   If you have to go through javascript,  then I'm pretty sure that means you'll need to use the browser,  which unfortunately means your gonna get a warning..